# Filter list based on distinct and second predicate

Tags: java, data-structures, java-stream

My object looks like following

```
Store {
   String shopId;
   long distance;
}
```

I got a list of stores.

```
List<Store> storesList = Arrays.asList(
    new Store (1, 1),
    new Store (1, 5),
    new Store (2, 2),
    new Store (1, 1), // this is duplicate
    new Store (1, 2),
    new Store (1, 1), // this is duplicate
    new Store (3, 7)
    new Store (3, 5)
);
```

Output

```
Store {shopId=1, distance=1}  // its fine to have any one among 3 duplicates
Store {shopId=2, distance=2}
Store {shopId=3, distance=5}
```

i can call my own distint method like following

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Map<Object, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

and filter it like this

```
List<Store> stores= storesList .stream()
        .filter(distinctByKey(pr -> Arrays.asList(pr.getShopId())))
        .collect(toList());
```

but how to filter it at the same time by smaller distance too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 storesList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Store::getShopId,
                Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Store::getDistance))
              ))
           .values()
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can merge these same `Store`s (by `storeId`), where you would say that when merging you would take the smallest `distance` between two Stores.

Answer (score 2):

If you sort the stream by distance before filter, you will get the smallest distances:

```java
List<Store> stores = storesList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Store::getDistance))
        .filter(distinctByKey(it -> it.shopId))
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Collection<Store> stores = storesList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Store::getShopId, 
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Store::getDistance)), 
                        Optional::get)))
        .values();
```

At the beginning you are grouping by `shopId`, then you are using the value with the minimum `distance`. At the Ende you are just using the values of this map as result.

If you need a List instead oft a Collection you can just use

```
new ArrayList<>(stores);
```